# how to remove MarkerOptions objects in google api v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I added some Markers in my map and now I want to remove them. Is there any method that I can use to remove my Marker? I used MarkerOptions class to build my Markers and add() method of GoogleMap to add them. And I have a reference of all of my Markers in a List.
I really need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the marker it is possible to obtain its reference:

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(..);
```

Marker class has remove method:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#remove

Removes this marker from the map. After a marker has been removed, the behavior of all its methods is undefined.

```
marker.remove()
```

It will remove all the markers. use this one to remove particular one

```
for(Marker m : marker)
m.remove();
```